# Migrating YAWL files (*.ywl) to BPMN 2.0 schema files

Tags: jbpm, activiti, bpmn, camunda, yawl

I'm trying to migrate from YAWL engine to another workflow engine, but I have about 500 (*.ywl) files, which I'm trying to convert to BPMN 2.0 and I think it's not reasonable to convert all of them manually.
The question is if there is any tool to convert all of these files automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, I just learned about [YAWL](http://yawlfoundation.org/) and I am indeed very interested in Buisness Process Modeling (BPM). In other words, it does not seem to be too wide spread in the European business world.

The cool thing is that for both BPMN and YAWL is stored as XML which means that they are [XML Schema Definition (XSD)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) for both of them:

> XSD can be used to express a set of rules to which an XML document must conform in order to be considered "valid" according to that schema. However, unlike most other schema languages, XSD was also designed with the intent that determination of a document's validity would produce a collection of information adhering to specific data types.

1. For BPMN, there are five relevant XSDs, see http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/
2. For YAWL, I found a [YAWL schema XSD on github](https://github.com/yawlfoundation/yawl/blob/master/schema/YAWL_SchemaBeta6.xsd) but I am not sure whether that is the relevant one.

This should give you a head start if you are forced to write some yawl2bpmn converter yourself.

#### Further reading

- [Short recipe how to write a .NET parser for BPMN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18722819)
- [How to transform XML for one XSD into another XML format that is very similar but has a different XSD file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484912/how-to-transform-xml-for-one-xsd-into-another-xml-format-that-is-very-similar-bu)
- Discussion on the topic within the [Camunda forum](https://forum.camunda.org/t/migrate-from-yawl-activiti-to-camunda/13966)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not, you will have to make a parser to translate to bpmn xml.